# iOS 5 - 1 Custom UINavigationBar different than all others

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I'm using UIAppearance in iOS 5 to create a custom UINavigationBar. I use the following code (inside AppDelegate.m) to give all of the navigation bars the same background

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarNoText.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I'd like to be able to use 1 navbar "NavBarWithText.png" for only 1 TableViewController, while I use the NavBarNoText.png as the background for all of the other navigation bars except for said TableViewController. Does anyone know if this is possible? I know Instagram does something like it, with the home tab using a different navigation bar than all of the other tabs.

I've tried using this separately in the ViewDidLoad method in each separate class, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the single view to have a different background at first, but it changes back to the common background after I switch a view.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarWithText.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

For the single view

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarNoText.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

For all of the other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` to show different navigationBar when displayed in `UITableViewController` for more information see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010906)

Comment: Ok I tried appearanceWhenContained in, but I still only see "NavBarNoText.png" Do I put the appearanceWhenContained in code in the customizeAppearance method in AppDelegate.m, or should I put it in TableViewController.m?

Comment: you have to give the class name for your TableViewController's class